# Process Spawns With "stdio: 'inherit' " But Not "stdio: 'pipe' "

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, sockets, asynchronous

I'm trying to pipe the console output of a child Python process to a parent Node.js process. I'm able to spawn a Python process successfully, and the output from the Node parent process successfully is outputted live to the webpage.

However, I can't send the output from the child process (Python script). The Python script successfully launches if I use the parameter "stdio: 'inherit'", but I require "stdio: 'pipe'", to output the terminal, and for some reason it doesn't work.

Server Code

```js
app.post('/clientwebpageoutput', function(req,res)
{
    var io = require('socket.io')(http);
    var child = require('child_process'); 
    var events = require('events');
    var eventEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();
    eventEmitter.on('logging', function(message) {
      io.emit('log_message', message);
    });
    io.on('connection', function(socket){
        console.log('Before process begins');
        var python_process = child.spawn( 'python3', ['snowboymultiplemodels.py'], {stdio: 'pipe'}); 
        var chunk = '';
        python_process.stdout.on('data', function(data){
            chunk += data
            socket.emit('newdata', chunk);
        } );
        python_process.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
            console.log('Failed to start child process.');
        })
});
    // Override console.log
    var originConsoleLog = console.log;
    console.log = function(data) {
      eventEmitter.emit('logging', data);
      originConsoleLog(data);
    };
    res.render('clientwebpageoutput'); //,output);
});
```

Client (successfully outputs stderr):

```html
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
      $(function () {
        var socket = io();
        socket.on('log_message', function(msg){
         $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
        });
      });
</script>
```

Why does the process not spawn? The terminal always shows the error message created above in stderr ("Failed to start child process").

Comment: Standard error is just another output stream; receiving data from it doesn’t mean the process failed to spawn (actually the opposite), or even that it’s failing to carry out its task. Have you tried `console.log(data.toString())`?

Comment: I have tried that, and in that case the process also spawns, but the problem is the slightly different (thought it might overload the question). I see the output of the Python process in the node terminal, but on the webpage (and the node terminal) all I see is "Failed to start process". The "Failed to start process" message emits whenever a line from the Python process emits.

Comment: I mean in the `stderr.on('data')` listener, replacing the incorrect “Failed to start child process”.

Comment: Yes sorry, I realized when I tried it I never replaced the incorrect "Failed to start child process". Thank you so much! Can you post your comment in the form of an answer so I can accept it?